# How to combine a custom date and time field in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm looking for a way to combine a custom date value and a time field in django. My model only contains a time field. Now I have to annotate a new field combining a custom date and the time field. I thought the following code will solve my problem, but it only gives the date value. TimeField is ignored.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   my_time_field = TimeField()

custom_date = datetime.today().date()
objects = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    custom_datetime=Func(
        custom_date + F('my_time_field'),
        function='DATE'
    )
)
```

Please advise the right way to solve this issue.

Comment: Why do you to include a date if the date has nothing to do with your database? What is it that you're actually trying to do with this value?

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code. I need to do further filtering based on the newly created field (custom_datetime).

Comment: I assumed so, so why not use `DateTimeField()` instead so you can filter on it without having to worry about hacking stuff together? By adding a given date to a time seems silly because the date has nothing to do with the object.

Comment: Like I said, my actual code is really complicated one. It has to dynamically generate dates based on user input. But TimeField remains the same. I just wanted to know if this is possible with django.

Answer (score 0):

It was an easy solution, but took a while for me to figure it out. If anyone else having the same question, this is the answer. Just use `ExpressionWrapper`.

```
objects = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    custom_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
        custom_date + F('my_time_field'),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use a `Value` expression (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions)) in a manner similar to this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_time_field = TimeField()

custom_date = datetime.today().date()
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    custom_datetime=Value(
        datetime.datetime.combine(custom_date, F('my_time_field')),
        output_field=DateTimeField()))
```

The key parts are to combine your `custom_date`, the time from your `my_time_field`, and then output it as a `DateTimeField`.

Comment: Straight forward way. But it won't work. datetime.combine() cannot have F() or any other expression as argument. Only datetime.date and datetime.time are accepted.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe you can use a lambda expression?

Comment: How? I think only database level function can help on this. My actual code is inside a Subquery, which is inside a Prefetch. :)

Comment: Yes, maybe you just need to skip the ORM and do a raw query :(